# Finding element of order in the symmetric group

Tags: group-theory, permutations

What is the proper and technical way to find if there exists an element in the symmetric group $S_n$ ([Wikipedia article on symmetric groups.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group)). I do know how to disprove if there does not exists such elements, but how should I find the element which does exists of this order?

For example, in the $S_{12}$, there is not such element of order $13$ because The only elements of order $13$ in $S_n$ are unions of disjoint $13$-cycles, since $13$ is prime. This would require $S_{12}$ to contain at least $13$ symbols, which it does not. But I think that there is an element of order $35$ in $S_{12}$. How should I find it?

**EDIT**: I do understand that I have to find a $7$-cycle and a $5$-cycle, but how?

Comment: $35=5\times 7$.

Comment: [First, prove that the order of an element in $S_n$ equals the least common multiple of the lengths of the cycles in its cycle decomposition.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419937/prove-that-the-order-of-an-element-in-s-n-equals-the-least-common-multiple-of)
Hence, by the answer provided by @Ross, you can prove your claim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an element of order $k$, you can factor $k$ and make some cycles whose $\operatorname {LCM}$ is $k$.  In your example of $35$ we note that $35=5\cdot 7$, so if you make a $5-$cycle and a $7-$cycle you will have an element of order $35$.  As $5+7=12$ you have enough room to do this in $S_{12}$

Comment: Thanks I get it now. How can I find the maximum order possible?

Comment: $35$ is the best you can do with just two cycles, but once $n$ gets large enough you can do better with three separate cycles.  $12$ is large enough that three cycles gives a higher LCM.  Values of the maximum are given in http://oeis.org/A000793

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* $35 = 5 \cdot 7$ and $5+7=12$.